# Stepping into an stream of data and outputting an array of filtered data Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, functional-programming, rxjs

I have a stream of data coming in so I used a `flatMap` to break into it to have this.

[image]

From the `flatMap`, I wanted the hero object so I used a `map` to step into that and then subscribed. Now my problem is, the data arrives at the `subscribe` individually. As shown below.

[image]

I would want to collect everything during the stream and then output an array of all the data in the subscribe.

Here is my code.

```
this.subscription = this.heroService.getAll()
.flatMap(h=>{ console.log("From flatMap",h); return h})
.map((h : any)=>h.hero)
 .subscribe(heroes => {
   console.log("From subscribe",heroes);
 })
```

I would like the subscribe to look like something like below.

[image]

How do I go about that?

Comment: Is it always 2 values you are waiting for?

Comment: No. Not just two values. Tried with `pairwise()` and I realized that it returns only two values.

Comment: can you add sample input and output json data

Comment: The input data is coming from firebase and it's quite messy with a whole lot of info. When filtered, it looks like the flatMap image I have posted above. In fact, when I subscribe to it to retrieve the data, it produces the flatMap image above

Comment: If you remove `flatMap` and `map`, what you will get on each emission? I mean, if you just subscribe to your source observable? (`getAll()`)

Comment: Like I said, same as the flatMap. Here is an image to show that 
 https://ibb.co/gdVaLw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want subscribe to receive an array of heroes, don't use flatMap.  Just use map:

```
this.subscription = this.heroService.getAll()
.map((results:Array<any>) => results.map(r => r.hero))
 .subscribe(heroes => {
   console.log("From subscribe",heroes);
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toArray()` operator.

Be aware that `toArray()` requires the source Observable to complete. Otherwise it won't emit anything. If you know it won't complete you can use the `scan()` operator and collect the items yourself.

Comment: Please can you be a little specific. Where does the `toArray()` or `scan()` fit into the whole chain? After flatMap?, map?